# ESLint "no-multi-spaces" rule is not working in Vue methods or computed when using multiple spaces between function name and paren

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

ESLint `no-multi-spaces` rule is not working in Vue methods or computed when using multiple spaces between function name and paren.
It only working in between paren and curly.

[Screenshot: no-multi-spaces working only between paren and curly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQiIo.png)

[Screenshot: My expected result(it's not Vue.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baUji.png)

I also tried `vue/no-multi-spaces` and `space-before-function-paren`.
But `vue/no-multi-spaces` not working at all,
and `space-before-function-paren` can't fix number of spaces.

This is my rule.
`'no-multi-spaces': ['error', { ignoreEOLComments: true }]`

How can I use like below?

```
/* GOOD */
foo () {
}

/* BAD */
foo() {
}
bar     () {
}
```

Comment: FWIW `foo()` is common formatting and `foo ()` is not, it's possible that there are no means to achieve your goal because it's undemanded by most users

Comment: Eslint [no-multi-spaces](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-multi-spaces) works fine in Vue 3 cause of the keyword 'function' before your methods, but I believe there is no way to make it works with vue2 in the way you want except if you use prettier with it. You can use prettier/prettier as plug-in of eslint to make it work. [vue/no-multi-spaces](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-multi-spaces.html) can't work either, it only works in the template part. Can you give us the version of ESlint you are using ?

Comment: @Samuel I use Vue 2 and latest ESLint(8.38.0). 
But... regardless of Vue, isn't it in the form of Object's methods? 
(e.g. `methods.foo()`, `computed.bar()`)